# How to show that adding more data improve a model quality?

Tags: regression, dataset, model

I am working on a project for university and I would like to demonstrate that adding more rows to the same model (linear regressions for instance or other types of models) increase the model quality. By quality I mean it would overfit less, and generalize better.

For the first dataset I have around 180 rows, while the second dataset contains around 1400 rows (additional rows were generated through various methods and are similar up to 70% to the initial dataset).

When I train a simple linear regression model (with OLS). I get better results on the smaller model than the second with more data. I was thinking that the error was smaller because there was less rows (computing average error for 180 rows will probably give a lower error than computing it for 1400 rows).

Although the second model with more data is theoretically better, how I can measure its quality ? (I tried using AIC and BIC but they are much lower in the model with less data).

Comment: It's not true that more data are necessarily better. For example, trivially but important as a principle, I can get a perfect fit from a line fitted to two data points that are distinct on two variables, but I can't maintain that perfect performance in practice as I add more data. In your case everything hinges on what if anything changes as you add more data. For example, the smaller sample might be more nearly homogeneous than the larger sample. If you shuffle your data to shake out any structure, some measures of fit should not change much, Results dependent on sample size will change.

Comment: There are several ambiguities in your question: what is average error and in what sense does the regression fit minimise that?  What are the "various methods" you use?

Comment: @NickCox Thank's for the clarification, I'm using RMSE and MAE as a measure of error (with Cross validation on 4 folds), by various methods it's using simulation (event based simulation of the process that generated this data) and also using a newer deep learning based technique (CTGAN)

Comment: @NickCox For instance, is it possible to show that for a small dataset, a random forest will probably overfit it while for a larger one it would generalize better ?

Comment: You need an expert on random forests to get a worthwhile comment. You need a design that separates effects of changing sample size from anything else that might change.